# Query condtion for values not being the default value?

Tags: mysql

Can I reference a columns default value directly in a query?

Something like this: `SELECT column FROM table WHERE column <> column.DEFAULT_VALUE`

Background: I'm writing a application test, and I want to easily find out which columns have non-default values. I could parse out the default value from the schema definition which is stored on disc, or figure out what the default is in various more or less convoluted ways, but I'm hoping there's a syntax for asking the server directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name alas, there is ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, in MySQL. You can use the **[`DEFAULT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default)** function:

```
SELECT column 
FROM table 
WHERE NOT (column <=> DEFAULT(column)) ;
```

Instead of `<>`, the `NOT (.. <=> ..)` construct that uses the [null-safe equal operator **`<=>`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is needed for nullable columns, to have values returned when the default is `NULL` and null values returned when the default is not null.

Tested in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/144601/4)